# Is it safe to boil carbonated water in a kettle : Why's it 'unclear what you're asking'?

Tags: discussion

I rewrote [Is it safe to boil carbonated water in a kettle?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/112831/7952) a minute ago, but I saw no comments counselling what was unclear?

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that it may not be the only reason it was closed, but unclear was the one that got the most votes. 2 distinct questions in one question is technically "*too-broad*" so that may have been another reason.

To answer your question about unclear, my analysis is:

> <del>I know and desire that boiling carbonated water removes all the dissolved CO2, but I worry that boiling in a kettle can endanger me?</del>
>
> Isn't it dangerous to boil carbonated water in a kettle?

What does dangerous mean? Dangerous how? Why do you think carbonated water is more dangerous than normal water? It's hard to imagine what a good answer would look like.

> Whenever I boil water in my kettle, I close its lid. Does this close lid constitute 'under pressure' (and so danger) emboldened beneath?

I think for the last part "*'under pressure' (and so danger) emboldened beneath*" I don't think embolden is the right word for what you want to ask, thus it is unclear.